# How would you create a summary zoo from a list of files?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Suppose I have a number of csv files that have the following format:

```
Date,col1,col2,col3
8/1/2017,2,3,4
8/5/2017,4,6,7

Date,col1,col2,col3
8/1/2017,2,3,4
8/3/2017,2,5,4
8/5/2017,4,6,7
```

How would I create a 1 zoo object that for each date shows me a total for each column?

Using the file contents above I would like to create the following zoo object:

```
Date      | col1 | col2 | col3
8/1/2017      4     6      8
8/3/2017      2     5      4
8/5/2017      8    12     14
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R solution (using zoo package is OK)

Comment: Is the format %m/%d/%Y or `%d/%m/%Y

Comment: How do you plan on creating a `zoo` object via base R?

Comment: Not my downvote Denis but If I took a guess, the downvote is because you show no effort in solving this yourself

Comment: @Sotos, akrun gave me a good base and I figured out the rest... I updated his answer below... I didn't know how to read-in the files so zoo doesn't create a column for each column in each file. The `lapply` trick is what I was missing.

Comment: No I meant how would you create an actual `zoo` object using only base R (as your request at the end). Sorry If I misunderstood. I thought there was a base R function for `read.zoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.zoo` by reading the files in a list with `lapply`

```
library(zoo)

files <- list.files("C:\\test", pattern = ".*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
out.list <- lapply(files, function(x) read.zoo(x, header=TRUE, sep = ",", index.column = "Date"))
summary <- Reduce("+", do.call(merge, args = c(out.list, retclass = "list", fill = 0)))
colnames(summary) <- colnames(out.list[[1]])
```

Comment: @Denis Thanks, but wouldn't you require the `format`